# New To React Hook useState Is Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, undefined, react-hooks

`useState()` is giving me undefined to the new state variable (notifications):

```
const Notifications = (props) => {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState(props.notifications);//notifications = undefined, props = {notifications: Array(0)}
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.notifications) {
        setNotifications(props.notifications);
        }
    }, [props.notifications]);
    // do stuff....
```

I am expecting notifications to be `[]` and then subsequently update it with `setNotifications()` when `props.notifications` changes. `props.notification` is coming from a redux store. I don't know if this changes anything but i did set an initial State.

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  notifications: [],
});
```

Don't know why i am getting undefined...

Edit: Got rid of typo and testing code

Comment: if you want to set initialState an empty array then initialize empty array in `useState([])`

Comment: @binodstha7 I tried using `useState([])` but `notifications` become undefined inside the `useEffect()`.

Comment: If you're seeing the `notifications` variable getting set to `undefined`, then you're passing it `undefined` for the initial value to `useState`. Is your component rendering once with notifications and then again without? You're making an assumption that some code we can't see is working, and it isn't.

Comment: check what is comming in `props.notification` by `console.log(props.notification)` in `useEffect` method if props.notification consoled undefined than you have problem in redux part.

Comment: the state will get set once so make sure props.notifications is not undefined initially

Comment: looks like a typo to me: `notification` without `s` somewhere?

Comment: This was happening for me when I accidentally had brackets instead of parenthesis for `useState(0)`

Answer (score 11):

To set initial state properly you should pass it to the `useState` as an argument, so:

```
const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);
```

Also no matter if you set `props.notifications` outside somewhere or not, but if you rely on it having some kind of default value in the component, then you should set it right there, e.g.:

```
const Notifications = ({ notifications = [] }) => {
```

And the last but not the least, using array in dependency list of `useEffect` has some unwanted side-effects, for example if `notifications` structuruly will stay the same (same items, same length), but will be a new array, `useEffect` will miss a cache, since it only does a shallow comparison. Consider using a hashing function of some kind instead of the array itself (e.g. `JSON.stringify`)

Comment: Instead of using a hashing function, I suggest creating new arrays. New state? Entirely new objects for the changed values.